# Can't submit change: client-side verification fails on unedited section

Tags: bug

I'm trying to change some of the entries in the table under "Character Guide" on [Getting started with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/259/getting-started-with-regular-expressions). But when I click "Submit for Review", I get a red popup error message on the "Versions" section saying that the Versions section can only contain tables and headings. I didn't even change anything in Versions. However, it does display my changes when I log in, so maybe it has gone into the moderation system. (If so, then I've been spamming the moderators with multiple attempts :-o )

Comment: I doubt that this is specific to stackoverflow. All the sites use the same software don't they? I added details it's considered good practice to add details for bug reports just in case they're relevant (e.g. operating system, software version, etc). But whatever is wrong with that page for me could probably just as easily happen on another page on another site. (Although I admit it's too early to be sure about this.) So I still think it should be asked here, not on stackoverflow meta.

Comment: "I doubt that this is specific to stackoverflow" It is documentation specific and [so] is the only site so far that has documentation ...

Comment: I didn't know that. Fair enough then.